# Division: Why is \frac9{17}= 0.529.. and not $0.5209$?

Tags: arithmetic

I am frequently coming across the following issue.

If we divide a by b and b>a, then we move to the decimal points and we add a zero for every step right? Could someone explain why?

For non decimal points we do not do it, but for the decimal points we do.

So 9/17, 17>9 thus we move right.

90/17 = 5

-85

50

Now 17<50, so we stop to move right until such situations?

Maybe I understand this now, we move right and add the zero to the left point.

Is this the concept? Move right & add zero, still divisor>numerator? repeat.

So at the point 0.52 we only require one move to the right, thus it is not 0.520

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to remember what happens to the decimal points is to remember that what you are really doing here is **multiplying by one** by noting that $\frac{10}{10} = 1$. Here is how it works with your example:

\begin{align}
\frac{9}{17} &= 1 \cdot \frac{9}{17} \\
&= \frac{10}{10} \cdot \frac{9}{17} \\
&= \frac{1}{10} \cdot \frac{90}{17} \\
&= \frac{1}{10} \cdot \frac{85 + 5}{17} \\
&= \frac{1}{10} \cdot \left( \frac{85}{17} + \frac{5}{17} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{10} \cdot \left( 5 + \frac{5}{17} \right) \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{10} \cdot 5\right) + \left(\frac{1}{10} \cdot \frac{5}{17}\right) \\
&= 0.5 + \left( \frac{1}{10} \cdot \frac{5}{17} \right).
\end{align}
The last equality comes from the fact that multiplying by $\frac{1}{10} = 0.1$ "shifts the decimal one place to the right." Now we note that $5 < 17,$ so we repeat.
\begin{align}
\frac{9}{17} &= 0.5 + \left( \frac{1}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{10} \cdot \frac{50}{17}\right) \\
&= 0.5 + \frac{1}{100} \cdot \frac{34 + 16}{17} \\
&= 0.5 + \frac{1}{100} \left(2 + \frac{16}{17}\right) \\
&= 0.5 + \left(\frac{1}{100} \cdot 2\right) + \left( \frac{1}{100} \cdot \frac{16}{17} \right) \\
&= 0.5 + 0.02 + \left( \frac{1}{100} \cdot \frac{16}{17} \right) \\
&= 0.52 + \frac{1}{1000} \cdot \frac{160}{17}.
\end{align}
On the last step, I did the same multiplication by $1 = \frac{10}{10}$ as before. Notice how we are at the third stage and we have a $\frac{1}{1000}$ being multiplied and $1000 = 10 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 = 10^3$ is just $10$ multiplied by itself three times. This means that your next intermediate step will have the decimal shifted three times. Four steps will lead to four decimal shifts because you will end up multiplying by $\frac{1}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{1000} = \frac{1}{10000} = \frac{1}{10 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 \cdot 10} = \frac{1}{10^4}$ is dividing by $10$ four times, which means shift the decimal four times. Going five steps will shift the decimal five places, six steps will shift it six, and so on.

Comment: Damn, thanks. I did not think about it this way.